# Gmail app for university students

Tags: gmail, domain

We have a domain and hosting at `hostmonster.com` for our university. Now we want to give students facility to create their own email account under university domain. And we want to use Gmail web app for this.

Is it possible and how to accomplish that?

Comment: I think you are looking for [Google Apps for Education](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/edu/).

Answer (score 2):

You probably refer to Google Apps, which lets you host Google services like Gmail, Calendar and Docs on your own domain.

Google Apps has a special interesting offer for universities and schools called Apps for Education. Check it out here: http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/edu/